# How to remove quotation marks from matplotlib axis label (generated from a merged list) in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code, what is the right way to print the y ticks as E 40% instead of ('E', 40, '%') i.e. no brackets, quotation marks and no space between 40 and %?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

a = [20, 40, 60, 120, 160]  # number of samples of each classes
b = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']  # different types of classes
c = [5, 10, 15, 30, 40]  # percentage of samples in each classes
d = ['%' for i in range(0, len(a))]
e = list(zip(b, c, d))

plt.barh(b, a)
plt.xlabel('Number of Samples')
plt.ylabel('Different Classes')
plt.yticks(ticks = b, labels = e)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyEeK.png)

Comment: Can you write code that converts the tuple `('E', 40, '%')` into the corresponding string `'E40%'`? Can you write code that applies that to each element of `e`?

Comment: `e = [f'{bi} {ci}%' for bi, ci in zip(b, c)']`.  Note that `for i in range(0, len(a))` is very unpythonic.  Explicit indices are usually avoided. You could write `['%'] * len(a)`.  See e.g. this article: [Stop using indices](https://www.codementor.io/@philbest/stop-using-indices-woab0mh1t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a tuple of the elements in b, c, and d in the `list(zip(..))` command. What you should be doing is just combining them in some other way, which can easily be done in a list comprehension:

```
e = ['{:s} {:d}%'.format(b[i],c[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

To explain this, this code creates a string of the format "string value%" by using the values in your lists b and c. This also negates the use of the "%" list which is completely redundant since you use a percent sign in every list (if you use multiple symbols than this might be necessary, however, and you can simply put another {:s} field with the formatted d[i] value in the string above).

Subbing in the new list in your current code results in:
[image: your new graph]

Comment: It works great for this example! However, if any of the lists b or c consists of floats rather than integers, it results in the following errors:  "ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'". What should you replace the 'd' within the list comprehension 'e'?

Comment: So, {:d} in a string means that the format function expects an integer. I can't really answer your question because it's up to you how you want to format it. I can just explain that {:.2f} will expect a float, and print and to two decimal points. You can also cast your float to an int if that is acceptable (`.format(b[i],int(c[i])`)

Comment: That actually works, great! I can just use 1f, 2f or so to the desired decimal points and that's perfect!

Comment: Great, would you mind accepting my answer since it worked for you please :)